# Filtering overlay for holes and then pushing it to the Data Layer without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I have an issue with the DrawManager drawing and exporting the overlays into a GeoJSON object.

I can draw a polygon with holes in the DrawManager and the overlays will show holes in the object. The problem is when exporting this to the DataLayer.

The datalayer makes exporting GeoJSON easy. Regarding holes: [polygon data layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-polygon)

```
map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([
    outerCoords,
    innerCoords1,//hole
    innerCoords2, //hole
    ]),
});
```

How can I export the DrawManager drawing to fit this schema?

I've attempted a solution using the rewinded path on the datalayer. However I cannot get the holes to link to the polygon with holes. It creates duplicates. The DrawingManager shows the data but I'm struggling exporting this data to look like the drawn image.

Drawn image:
[image]

Output GeoJSON data:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[150.3308896484375,-34.242748228904865],[150.0232724609375,-34.555492148137766],[150.764849609375,-34.70465158215243],[151.0779599609375,-34.27452911659509],[150.3308896484375,-34.242748228904865]]]},"properties":{}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[150.3308896484375,-34.242748228904865],[150.0232724609375,-34.555492148137766],[150.764849609375,-34.70465158215243],[151.0779599609375,-34.27452911659509],[150.3308896484375,-34.242748228904865]],[[150.8362607421875,-34.41512862111033],[150.35835546875,-34.51476578284105],[150.53413671875,-34.392467230948675],[150.8362607421875,-34.41512862111033]]]},"properties":{}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[150.3308896484375,-34.242748228904865],[150.0232724609375,-34.555492148137766],[150.764849609375,-34.70465158215243],[151.0779599609375,-34.27452911659509],[150.3308896484375,-34.242748228904865]],[[150.44624609375,-34.35619624254908],[150.237505859375,-34.49213141771243],[150.1606015625,-34.47854784880349],[150.369341796875,-34.29722239841581],[150.44624609375,-34.35619624254908]]]},"properties":{}}]}
```

Plotted Output:
[image: Duplicates in the layers]
The data is not appending holes it's re-creating the [outer,inner] datalayer.

**code snippet:**

```js
    // This example requires the Drawing library. Include the libraries=drawing
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIwzALxUPNbatRBj3Xi1Uhp0fFzwWNBkE&libraries=drawing">
    function initMap() {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: {
                lat: -34.397,
                lng: 150.644
            },
            zoom: 8,
        });
        const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
                ],
            },
        });
        var dataLayer = new google.maps.Data();
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
        var overlayArr = [] //Store all completed objects
        var holeArr = [] //Keep track of holes to build polygon with data layer
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
            if (e.type === 'polygon') {
                console.log("overlaycomplete start overlayArr.length=" + overlayArr.length);
                var path = e.overlay.getPath().getArray()
                path = rewindRing(path, true);
                var found = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < overlayArr.length; i++) {
                    if (isPolygonInsidePolygon(e.overlay, overlayArr[i])) {
                        found = true;
                        var path = e.overlay.getPath().getArray();
                        path = rewindRing(path, false);
                        overlayArr[i].getPaths().push(new google.maps.MVCArray(path))
                        dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
                            geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([overlayArr[i].getPath().getArray(), path]) //Store holes as the secondary "outer" to save to GeoJSON
                        }));
                        holeArr.push(overlayArr[i]);
                        e.overlay.setMap(null); //make hole
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    overlayArr.push(e.overlay);
                    //This is a duplicate object in the datalayer after a hole is drawn -- how to remove if hole is drawn?
                    dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
                        geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([e.overlay.getPath().getArray()]) //No holes add normal
                    }));
                    found = false;
                }
            }
            if (e.type === 'circle') {
                dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
                    properties: {
                        radius: e.overlay.getRadius()
                    },
                    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point(e.overlay.getCenter())
                }));
            }
        });
    
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('save'), 'click', function() {
            dataLayer.toGeoJson(function(obj) {
                document.getElementById('geojson').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
            });
        })
    
        //Helper function
        function isPolygonInsidePolygon(innerPolygon, outerPolygon) {
            var points = innerPolygon.getPath().getArray();
    
            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                if (!google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(points[i], outerPolygon)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        // from https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-rewind/blob/main/index.js
        function rewindRing(ring, dir) {
            var area = 0;
            for (var i = 0, len = ring.length, j = len - 1; i < len; j = i++) {
                area += ((ring[i].lng() - ring[j].lng()) * (ring[j].lat() + ring[i].lat()));
            }
            console.log("area=" + area + " dir=" + dir);
            if (area >= 0 !== !dir)
                ring.reverse();
            return ring;
        }
    }
```

```css
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drawing Tools</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
  <input id="save" value="save" type="button" />
  <div id="geojson"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing&v=weekly" async></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to repopulate the datalayer if a polygon has holes in order to prevent duplicate objects in the layer. For example if you draw a polygon and then another polygon inside of it as a hole--the original polygon will still be in the datalayer. I need to simply do a algorithm to re-generate the datalayer after all objects have been completed and then can use it for exporting.

Comment: The self contained polygon also cannot be exported toGeoJson (I think) with holes unless you use the datalayer

Comment: They can be added to the datalayer with the holes (if you pull out the paths), they can also be exported directly to GeoJSON if you write the code to do it (but using the DataLayer is probably easier).  The duplicate problem is another issue.

Comment: What do you suggest I do to pull out the paths of intersections in order to combine that to the data layer? Thanks for the help btw

Comment: I don't understand that comment in the context of your question.  What "intersections"?  (the problem with your question in general is that it isn't clear, seems to include multiple questions and doesn't include a [mcve] that clearly demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I've updated the question and fixed the example to show my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be not to add the polygons to the DataLayer until they need to be exported.  Remove the code that adds the polygons to the DataLayer as they are drawn, then make your export function like this:

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('export'), 'click', function() {
    for (var i=0; i<overlayArr.length;i++) {
      // for each polygon drawn, get its paths
      var paths = [];
      for (var j=0; j<overlayArr[i].getPaths().getLength();j++) {
        var path = [];
        for (k=0; k<overlayArr[i].getPaths().getAt(j).getLength(); k++) {
          path.push(overlayArr[i].getPaths().getAt(j).getAt(k));
        }
        paths.push(path);
      }
      // create a Data.Polygon
      map.data.add({
        geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon(paths)
      });    
    }
    // export the GeoJson from the Data Layer
    map.data.toGeoJson(function(geoJson){
      console.log(geoJson);
      document.getElementById('geoJson').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(geoJson);
    });
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zqnadxsk/5/)

[image: screenshot of polygon with two holes]

```js
// This example requires the Drawing library. Include the libraries=drawing
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIwzALxUPNbatRBj3Xi1Uhp0fFzwWNBkE&libraries=drawing">
    function initMap() {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: {
                lat: -34.397,
                lng: 150.644
            },
            zoom: 8,
        });
        const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
                ],
            },
        });
        var dataLayer = new google.maps.Data();
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
        var overlayArr = [] //Store all completed objects
        var holeArr = [] //Keep track of holes to build polygon with data layer
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
            if (e.type === 'polygon') {
                console.log("overlaycomplete start overlayArr.length=" + overlayArr.length);
                var path = e.overlay.getPath().getArray()
                path = rewindRing(path, true);
                var found = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < overlayArr.length; i++) {
                    if (isPolygonInsidePolygon(e.overlay, overlayArr[i])) {
                        found = true;
                        var path = e.overlay.getPath().getArray();
                        path = rewindRing(path, false);
                        overlayArr[i].getPaths().push(new google.maps.MVCArray(path))
                        dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
                            geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([overlayArr[i].getPath().getArray(), path]) //Store holes as the secondary "outer" to save to GeoJSON
                        }));
                        holeArr.push(overlayArr[i]);
                        e.overlay.setMap(null); //make hole
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    overlayArr.push(e.overlay);
                    //This is a duplicate object in the datalayer after a hole is drawn -- how to remove if hole is drawn?
                    dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
                        geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([e.overlay.getPath().getArray()]) //No holes add normal
                    }));
                    found = false;
                }
            }
            if (e.type === 'circle') {
                dataLayer.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
                    properties: {
                        radius: e.overlay.getRadius()
                    },
                    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point(e.overlay.getCenter())
                }));
            }
        });
    
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('export'), 'click', function() {
            dataLayer.toGeoJson(function(obj) {
                document.getElementById('geoJson').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
            });
        })
    
        //Helper function
        function isPolygonInsidePolygon(innerPolygon, outerPolygon) {
            var points = innerPolygon.getPath().getArray();
    
            for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                if (!google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(points[i], outerPolygon)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        // from https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-rewind/blob/main/index.js
        function rewindRing(ring, dir) {
            var area = 0;
            for (var i = 0, len = ring.length, j = len - 1; i < len; j = i++) {
                area += ((ring[i].lng() - ring[j].lng()) * (ring[j].lat() + ring[i].lat()));
            }
            console.log("area=" + area + " dir=" + dir);
            if (area >= 0 !== !dir)
                ring.reverse();
            return ring;
        }
    }
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 90%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drawing Tools</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="export" value="export" type="button" />
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="geoJson"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing&v=weekly" async></script>
  </body>
</html>
```